# Lifetime of Azure class-based Durable Entity instance

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Assume we have a trigger function acting as an orchestrator for a DurableEntityClient.  During the orchestration, we're chaining, then fanning-out, then aggregating... and an error occurs, and we return from the QueueTrigger.

What is the status of the DurableEntity?  Does it get disposed?  Or is there some clean-up that needs to be done that I haven't found in the documentation?  (If so, I apologize.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you give some code or error messages, this can help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FrankGong - Haven't written any code.  I'm simply trying to understand Durable Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to manage the client lifetime manually ([doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#terminate-instances) in case you haven't seen that one) it's generally not necessary. The primary instance I can think of where you would need to handle process termination in case of an error is if for some reason you aren't allowing the error to bubble up into the orchestration and instead you want to force it to timeout after a certain amount of time. I don't have an example of why you would want to do this, but it is a thing you could do.

As you've noticed, durable functions do offer a lot of control and configuration options, but they still hold to the Functions principle that you shouldn't need to handle these sorts of aspects of the host's life cycle. Instead the service handles that part for you.